# What causes this Objective-C compile error: Stray '\235' in Program

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
#import "InstatwitViewController.h"

@implementation InstatwitViewController


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerView {
 return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerViewnumberOfRowsInComponent :(NSInteger)component {

if (component == 0)
 return [activities count];
else
 return [feelings count]; 
}

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 activities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@”sleeping”, @”eating”, @”working”, @”thinking”, @”crying”, 
    @”begging”, @”leaving”, @”shopping”, @”hello worlding”, nil];
 feelings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@”awesome”, @”sad”, @”happy”, @”ambivalent”, 
    @”nauseous”, @”psyched”, @”confused”, @”hopeful”, @”anxious”, nil];
}



/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

 switch (component) { 
  case 0:
   return [activities objectAtIndex:row]; 
  case 1:
   return [feelings objectAtIndex:row];
 }
 return nil;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [activities release]; 
 [feelings release]; 
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

I get the following erros

> Stray '\235' in Program
>    - and 100 more with different numbers
>   Missing sentinel function call
>   Incomplete implementation of class InstatwitViewController

Any help, just doing a tutorial from a book, copied exactly, and don't see whats wrong

Comment: Didn't you leave out the first two stray errors, \342 and \200?  342 200 235 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201D ([RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). The CE/CP-1250 one would be 224 (octal) = 148 (decimal) = 0x94 (hexadecimal).

Comment: This is a duplicate. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)*.

Answer (score 8):

Your code contains smart quotes. They need to be straight quotes.

Lines like this:

```
activities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@”sleeping”, @”eating”, @”working”, @”thinking”, @”crying”, 
    @”begging”, @”leaving”, @”shopping”, @”hello worlding”, nil];
```

Need to be:

```
activities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sleeping", @"eating", @"working", @"thinking", @"crying", 
    @"begging", @"leaving", @"shopping", @"hello worlding", nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, it's bit me a few times too. (Mostly on shell scripting tips, which are typically blogged by someone who doesn't do a lot of code blogging.)

Answer (score 0):

the error probably is caused by `copied exactly`. It means you have at least one character in your code that the compiler cannot parse.